# Jolt specification in apache nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

input:

```json
{
  "eventid": "165",
  "name": "High memory utilization",
  "severity": "0",
  "userid": "1",
  "hosts": [
    {
      "hostid": "101",
      "proxy_hostid": "0",
      "host": "hostname",
      "name": "name"
    }
  ],
  "relatedObject": {
    "description": "High memory utilization",
    "comments": "The system is running out of free memory.",
    "uuid": ""
  },
  "tags": [
    {
      "tag": "component",
      "value": "memory"
    },
    {
      "tag": "class",
      "value": "os"
    },
    {
      "tag": "target",
      "value": "linux"
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected output

```json
{
  "severity" : "0",
  "name" : "High memory utilization",
  "host" : "hostname",
  "parameter" : "memory"
}
```

The tag component value should be assigned to parameter field. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Walk through the objects of the array as you want to get the value of the `value` key from the object, which is a member of tags array, having `tag` key with value which is equal to `component` after making tag value the key names of each of their nesting objects.

Then derive the values from the outer attributes by using these shift transformation specs

```json
[
  {
    // tag objects with the value of the tag keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "tags": {
        "*": {
          "@(2,severity)": "@(1,tag).severity", // go two levels up to grab the value from the attribute "severity"
          "@(2,name)": "@(1,tag).name",
          "@(2,hosts[0].host)": "@(1,tag).host", // go two levels up to grab the value from the array "hosts" and pick the first objects's "host" value among the objects nested within the array
          "value": "@(1,tag).&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // pick only the key-value pair from the object which's tagged "component"
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "component": ""
    }
  },
  {
    // replace the tag name of the attribute with "parameter"
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&", // "else" case (matches the attributes other than the below one)
      "value": "parameter" // rename the attribute "value" to "parameter"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks but i am sorry, my input is:  {"eventid": "165","name": "High memory utilization","severity": "0","userid": "1","hosts": [{
      "hostid": "101","proxy_hostid": "0","host": "hostname","name": "name" }],
  "relatedObject": {"description": "High memory utilization","comments": "The system is running out of free memory.", "uuid": ""
  },"tags": [{"tag": "component",  "value": "memory"},{"tag": "class","value": "os"},{  "tag": "target","value": "linux" }]} expected output:{
  "severity" : "0",
  "name" : "High memory utilization",
  "host" : "hostname",
  "parameter" : "memory"
}

Comment: please help me out

Comment: OK @Sathish I've just edited the answer.